# using mapView annotation in a tableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, mapkit

I'm a beginner but have been working really hard to build this application. Working from another question I asked: [mapkit and table view sample code - iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319669/mapkit-and-table-view-sample-code-iphone-sdk)

I was able to put together a (semi-)functioning tableview and mapview. However, I'm not really sure how to call the mapview annotations to do numberOfRowsInSection or cellForRowAtIndexPath.

the cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm sure isn't called properly but I'm thinking its a combo of both numberOfRowsInSection and cellForRowAtIndexPath.. But honestly I've been trying (and failing) for 3 weeks and reading all I can before I asked the question.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

//return [[mapView annotations] count];

return 1; }
```

So I was trying to use the count of the mapview annotations but I'm not even sure if this is working.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
}

NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //i'm sure the entire block below is pretty awful but i'm at a standstill

    for (MapLocation *annotation in [mapView annotations])
    {
        [annotations addObject:annotation];

        cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]title];

    }
return cell; //i'm pretty sure this shouldn't be here
```

}

If any other code is needed to help explain my situation just let me know.

Comment: Are the tableView and mapView in the same view controller?  What happens if you uncomment that line in numberOfRowsInSection?  How exactly is it failing?  Is there a compile error, run-time error?

Comment: would only be able to get 1 annotation to come into the tableview without it crashing on startup. It took me a few days but I've solved the issue but the numberOfRowsInSection still isn't very dynamic but I can live with it. I'll post my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

//return [[mapView annotations] count];

return 20;}
```

So I know that I only have 20 annotations at a time. This is still not ideal but it works

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{ static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitlereuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];}

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell =[[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
}

NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

if(indexPath.row < [[mapView annotations] count])
   {

    for (MapLocation *annotation in [mapView annotations])
    {
        [annotations addObject:annotation];

    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [[annotations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]title];

   }
    return cell;}
```

The tableview is populated with the annotation information. I found my solution by watching the UCDavis course with Serban Porumbescu (he was discussing tableviews and objects).

Comment: But what error does it crash with if you uncomment that line in numberOfRowsInSection?  The loop you have in cellForRowAtIndexPath is unnecessary and inefficient.  That method will be called by the table view once for each row every time that row becomes visible.  The code from `NSMutableArray *annotations = ...` and before `return cell;` can be replaced by: `cell.textLabel.text = [[[mapView annotations] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] title];`  Also, you have a memory leak (need to do `[annotations release];` before `return cell;`).

Comment: When I substitute in your code I get the error: 
                 "*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
*** Call stack at first throw:"

Comment: Did you also change the numberOfRowsInSection to return the actual count instead of "20"?

Comment: Hi Anna,No I can't get the numberOfRowsInSection to return the count. I've tried:    return [[mapView annotations] count]; but I'll keep looking to try to figure it out.